# How do I limit a user to three activities in a session in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone event that fires when the user clicks a next button. I want to limit the number of times a logged-out user can fire this event to three times before I force them to sign up. Is there a decent place/method to achieve this within the backbone framework?

My alternative is to use localStorage but I'm thinking there's likely a good way to do this natively in backbone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on your code structure, but you can perhaps store it as an attribute in your user data model if you have one, such as:

```
userdata.set('buttonFires', userdata.get('buttonFires')++);
```

Then, when the user clicks the button, check userdata on the click event to determine how to handle it.